# Elasticsearch JDBC River MySQL indexing freezes

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am trying to index a large database in elasticsearch using JDBC River for MySQL. However it seems to start but then just freezes before reading in any data. The log files are printing the following:

```
[2014-05-11 04:35:39,904][INFO ][org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.JDBCRiver] [Wade Wilson] [jdbc][search_deals]     starting JDBC river: URL [jdbc:mysql://hostname/database], strategy [simple], index/type     [search_deals/search_deal]
[2014-05-11 04:35:39,904][INFO ][org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverMouth] waiting for     cluster state YELLOW
[2014-05-11 04:35:39,906][INFO ][org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverMouth] ... cluster state ok
[2014-05-11 04:35:39,906][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Wade Wilson] [_river] update_mapping [search_deals] (dynamic)
[2014-05-11 04:35:39,936][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Wade Wilson] [_river] update_mapping [search_deals] (dynamic)
```

Can anyone help to find out why its not indexing. I waited many hours several times and it never started.

Comment: Did it at least post the river on the cluster?

Comment: It turned out there was a SQL error. It was mapping error, but it was strange that it wasn't complaining.